# How to enable the WooCommerce Sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website in made with `Wordpress 4.1.15` and I'm using the `WooCommerce` as a virtual store.

One of my admins deleted the `Checkout` and `Shop` pages, then I had to recover them from the trash but after that, the WooCommerce Sidebar disappear and now is disabled in the widgets area.

How can I force and enable again the sidebar?

Thansk

Answer (score 1):

Go to Shop edit page ant look at template. Select sidebar template if there is one. If there is no template with sidebar you have to create one.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, there is a template with the sidebar, but the main problem is that the widget area created by WooCommerce is disabled. and the widgets are not appearing. I tested your suggestion, but without success.

Comment: Check theme setings. If no succes wrote me a link mabe i could help. info@saitera.lt